# Number Count Start when we reach that point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We make on script for number count but the problem is that when we refresh and got to page number count start but We want when any one go that number or point then number count start.

Css:-

```
.office{padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;}
.office div{margin-bottom:5px;}
.office i {margin-right:0px;}
.office i img{width: 35px; height: 35px;}
.office div span{ font-size: 36px; position: relative; top: 10px;}
.office p{ font-size: 13px; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Js:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
});
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="row">
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div class="col-md-12 m-b-xm">
    <div class="col-xs-4 office">
      <div>
        <i><img src="images/office-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
    <span class="count">10</span>
  </div>
  <p>Offices Worldwide</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 office">
  <div>
    <i><img src="images/hard-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
    <span class="count" data-speed="1000">180</span>
  </div>
  <p>Hardworking People</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 office">
  <div>
    <i><img src="images/coun-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
    <span class="count">06</span>
  </div>
  <p>Countries Covered</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check link to full working code:- [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/s4cny1L5/)

Comment: Do you want that when the user reloads the page, the counters don't start over from one, but continue from the values that they have reached by the time the page was reloaded?

Comment: In case your goal is to start the counter when the user scrolls down to it and it comes on screen, check out the helper function described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling). You will need to call it when you expect that an element's visibility might have changed (e.g. on scroll event).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed you code a bit . check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4cny1L5/3/)

using data attribute like this

```
<span class="count" data-count="10">10</span>
```

we can track the count and then increment it.

Comment: Thanks this is oky, but I what this action on page scroll with auto start

Comment: @BharatNegi I have updated the fiddle , according to your requirement . check out

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">

  <div id="startcount"class="col-md-12 m-b-xm">
    <div class="col-xs-4 office">
      <div>
        <i><img src="images/office-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
        <span class="count">10</span>
      </div>
      <p>Offices Worldwide</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 office">
      <div>
        <i><img src="images/hard-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
        <span class="count" data-speed="1000">180</span>
      </div>
      <p>Hardworking People</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 office">
      <div>
        <i><img src="images/coun-ico.jpg" alt=""></i>
        <span class="count">06</span>
      </div>
      <p>Countries Covered</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
document.getElementById("startcount").onmouseover = function() {
 $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });  // code to run when the user hovers over the div
};
});
```

I think this is solve your problem...